# Pull in ALL posts from the last two weeks using Rest API

Tags: rest-api

So I am working with the WordPress REST API and I would like to pull in `all the posts from the last 2 weeks`, so approximately 14 days.

In the WordPress REST API arguments, they have a `before` and `after` argument (https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#example-request) that I might be able to utilize, but I'm unsure how to take this approach.

The WordPress REST API endpoint is being called using `$response = wp_remote_get`.

Here is my completed method to pull in ALL post for now:

```
public function get_posts_via_rest_api(): array
{
    $page = get_option('global_posts_page');
    if (!$page) {
        $page = 1;
    }
    try {
        $response = wp_remote_get(
            'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=' . $page
        );
        if ((!is_wp_error($response)) && (200 === wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response))) {
            $response_body = json_decode(
                $response['body'],
                false,
                512,
                JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR
            );

            return empty($response_body) ? [] : $response_body;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log(
            print_r(
                'Error: ' . $e,
                true
            )
        );

        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: To be clear, is the WordPress REST API which you are querying separate from the installation on which you're running this code? If they are the same installation, there's no reason to use the REST API - a `WP_Query` would suffice

Comment: @bosco, they are different websites, I'm pulling in posts from one of our websites to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP's [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to retrieve the timestamp for the date fourteen days ago, then [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to cast it into an ISO 8601-compliant string which can be passed into the `after` parameter.

I'm using `sprintf()` here to insert the date just to keep things a bit cleaner and avoid a mess of concatenation.

```php
$url = sprintf(
  'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?after=%s&page=%d',
  date( 'c', strtotime( '-14 days' ) ),
  $page
);
```

Comment: Thanks so much @bosco, I'll attempt this now!